# how to return value to previues page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm beginner in asp.net. My scenario :
I have Page1.aspx and a button that redirect to page2.aspx. 
There is a textbox On page1 and a textbox and a button on page2.
I want to show modal page2 and page1 wait for return a value that user typed in page2 and after page2 closed, show it in textbox in page1.
I don't know how to wait for closing page2 and how to send the value from page2 and get it in page1 .
please guide me . 
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You don't want Page2 to be a whole page... A browser can only have a single url open in any tab (unless you're using IFrames and they're not popular any more for a number of good reasons). By the time it's opened Page2, Page1 is gone forever. Instead, user (or make) a control for Page1 that has the button. Someone who's used ASP.Net more recently than me should be able to give you a good example.

Comment: similar to the above comment, make a modal popup all in Page1 (you can just use CSS for this) so it just appears to the user like a popup, but is not actually a separate page. Then you can handle all the interaction easily using javascript. There are plenty of tutorials online about it. Find one, try it and then ask a fresh question if you have a specific problem.

Comment: thanks for your replay. I know that . But I used page2 for search. So that I need to Create another page .

Comment: so you want the user to search for a value in page2, and then return the results and display the results in page1?

Comment: yes exactly.If you have a sample like this. I appropriate send me.

Comment: I think you are considering it still in terms of a desktop application, where multiple forms stay open at once. The web does not work like that. It's stateless. A form is shown, it posts back, and then it does not exist any more until another request is made from the browser. So your flow could be: Open page1. User requests search. navigate from page1 to page2. User enters search terms. Post the search terms to the server. Server processes them, and redirects to page1, and the server script renders the results onto the page from the variables store in the server.

Comment: p.s. this pattern is not specific to searching. It's just how programming for the web works. You can find hundreds of tutorials on how to display a form to the user, collect the entered data, process it, and display the results (with a redirect, if necessary).